# linux X server unexpected quit when Java started

Tags: java, linux, xserver

I am using opensuse linux, with proprietary Nvidia video driver. I found that when I try to plot a 3d figure using "surf" in Matlab, or start the emulator in Android Studio - which all calls some function in Java- the X session just quit. I have to log in again. I directed the output of the program to a log file, but there is no error message. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Did you capture stderr as well? `2>&1`

Comment: yes, that's what i did. nothing 〒_〒